# Mathematica and its use of Conditions, Assumptions and so on

Tags: assumptions, code-review, code-request

I don't understand why Mathematica has to be such a pain in the ***.

```
ComplexExpand[(I*ω)^(-3/4), TargetFunctions->{Re, Im}]
```

The result is

$$\frac{\cos \left(\frac{3}{4} \tan ^{-1}(0,\omega )\right)}{\left(\omega ^2\right)^{3/8}}-\frac{i \sin \left(\frac{3}{4} \tan ^{-1}(0,\omega )\right)}{\left(\omega ^2\right)^{3/8}}$$

Now, all good BUT the arctangent.

I have tried EVERYTHING I could to FORCE Mathematica to understand that $\omega$ is a NATURAL number, and nothing.

It doesn't get it. Assuming, Assumption, Conditions...

Is there a way to get rid of that useless arctangent terms, which is, by the way, nothing but $\frac{\pi}{2}$ considering that indeed $\omega >0$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you're looking for `Simplify` with the `Assumptions` option:  `Simplify[ComplexExpand[(I*\[Omega])^(-3/4)], 
 Assumptions -> {\[Omega] > 0}]`

Comment: @jjc385 That is very beautiful but then it gives me an expression in which real part and imaginary part are not separated anymore!

Comment: Ahh done! I found it out!

Answer (score 3):

Since I found the answer, I think it's good to give it.

Just use this:

```
ExpToTrig[Simplify[ComplexExpand[(I*ω)^(-3/4)], Assumptions -> {ω > 0}]]
```

And the output is:
$$\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)}{\omega ^{3/4}}-\frac{i \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)}{\omega ^{3/4}}$$

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out!  Have you also seen the [`Assuming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) function?  Note that it only has an effect on functions like `Simplify` which take an `Assumptions` option.

Comment: There is so much I still have to learn... Thank you!